# Invert functionality of row and column in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I want to display data about a Java Object in a JTable in my GUI. In a traditional JTable the rows are Objects (or whatever data representation) and the columns describe the data of the objects. I want to do the opposite. I want the rows to list the name of the data of the object and the column to show the value of the data.  I will only have 1 object in the table so I want the table to display data vertically instead of horizontally if that makes sense.

It appears that JTable is not designed to flip the functionality of rows and columns so my question is what is the best way to implement this? I know all of the names of the data I want to include as rows so I think I could just hardcode everything, but that doesn't seem very elegant.

Comment: *I want the table to display data vertically instead of horizontally if that makes sense.* - I'm not really understanding what you are asking. Please provide an ascii drawing showing how you want the data displayed.

Comment: Since you are describing you task in terms of “names”, “data”, and “objects”, there is no need to “flip the functionality of rows and columns”, as the terms “row” and “column” do not appear anywhere in the task description. You can implement a `TableModel` in any way you want.

Comment: @Holger Yep you are right. I spent a little more time thinking about my design and figured out how to represent the table